# Need help, Router wont render components for new url in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm having trouble rendering new urls when redirecting with a sidebar I implemented from the internet.

This is my App.js code:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
 import "./App.css";
 import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/sidebar";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>

        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/proyects"
            render={(props) => (
              <div>
                <h1>Proyects Render Try</h1>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is my sidebar.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  CDBSidebar,
  CDBSidebarContent,
  CDBSidebarFooter,
  CDBSidebarHeader,
  CDBSidebarMenu,
  CDBSidebarMenuItem,
} from "cdbreact";
import { NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import "./sidebar.css";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "100vh",
            overflow: "scroll initial",
          }}
        >
          <CDBSidebar textColor="#fff" backgroundColor="#333">
            <CDBSidebarHeader prefix={<i className="fa fa-bars fa-large"></i>}>
              <a
                href="/"
                className="text-decoration-none"
                style={{ color: "inherit" }}
              >
                Sidebar
              </a>
            </CDBSidebarHeader>

            <CDBSidebarContent className="sidebar-content">
              <CDBSidebarMenu>
                <NavLink exact to="/proyects" activeClassName="activeClicked">
                  <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="chart-line">
                    Proyects
                  </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
                </NavLink>

                <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="exclamation-circle">
                  404 page
                </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
              </CDBSidebarMenu>
            </CDBSidebarContent>

            <CDBSidebarFooter style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <div
                style={{
                  padding: "20px 5px",
                }}
              >
                Sidebar Footer
              </div>
            </CDBSidebarFooter>
          </CDBSidebar>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

When I click the proyects tab in my sidebar, the Url changes to "http://localhost:3000/proyects", but nothing new is rendered (Proyects Render Try). I've been able to make the router work with a react navbar, but can't seem to make the components render with this new sidebar.

Comment: Can you try to remove exact keyword in SideBar's NavLink component?  <NavLink to="/proyects" activeClassName="activeClicked">

Comment: Please add a return statement inside the Route render

Comment: I think I know what is happening. The sidebar is being rendered on top of the component. If I change the order and put the <Switch> on top of my <Sidebar> in my App.js, the component will show, but it will appear on top of my sidebar,  not to the right like a child would.